# ClamAV detects Malware : Java.Malware.Agent-6203119-0 FOUND

Tags: apache2, java, security, malware, clamav

My ClamAV daily scan is detecting Malware from apache-maven library location.
So now I want to know if this is a false positive or a real alert.

Can some one help me how to figure it out this? 
How can I exclude a particular file from the daily scan?

Find below logs I received after the daily scan.

```
/home/application/SSL/build-tools/apache-maven/lib/maven-model-builder-3.2.5.jar: Java.Malware.Agent-6203119-0 FOUND
----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 6302283
Engine version: 0.99.2
Scanned directories: 146811
Scanned files: 193145
Infected files: 1
Total errors: 12133
Data scanned: 9106.09 MB
Data read: 57098.23 MB (ratio 0.16:1)
Time: 2184.953 sec (36 m 24 s)
```

Comment: Assuming the .jar does not contain any critical data, consider checking it via virustotal.com. Its a free online scanner which features about 50-60 av-scanners at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advice to always do 2 things:

1. google file and malware notice.
2. check the integrity of the file.

---

1. There is not a single hit on google on "maven-model-builder-3.2.5.jar" and clamav reporting a virus in this file.
2. To check the integrity of this file the maven [repository](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-model-builder/3.2.5/) has 2 hashes:

   - [MD5 hash](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-model-builder/3.2.5/maven-model-builder-3.2.5.jar.md5) for it is: a216c67dae851a4cedb4b431a674eba2
   - [SHA1 hash](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-model-builder/3.2.5/maven-model-builder-3.2.5.jar.sha1) for it is: 7a32f3966fab463df9cdae95fd6df8c2e561e3ae

Commands to find those for your file are ...

```
md5sum /home/application/SSL/build-tools/apache-maven/lib/maven-model-builder-3.2.5.jar
sha1sum /home/application/SSL/build-tools/apache-maven/lib/maven-model-builder-3.2.5.jar
```

If those match: false positive. If they do not it needs more investigation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked the 2 hashes and they are matching. It seems like a false positive.

Comment: Yes, then those are false positives.